# python -m shows package as installed but can not find it

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook

If I run:

```
path/bin/python -m pip install jupyter
```

It shows `Requirement already satisfied: jupyter` and all the others packages, but then if I run:

```
path/bin/python -m jupyter notebook --no-browser --notebook-dir=~/ml/test/gpu-m1-availability-test.ipynb
```

I get:

```
path/bin/python: No module named jupyter
```

What am I missing? Why on one side it shows that is already satisfied but the trying to run it does not work?

**Config/Settings** to reproduce:
I'm on a mac with M1, using last miniforge version, with an environment created using those commands:

```
conda env create -f ml-apple-metal.yml -n ml-apple-metal
conda activate ml-apple-metal
conda install nb_conda
python -m ipykernel install --user --name ml-apple-metal --display-name "Python 3.9 (ML lib metal)"
```

and the `ml-apple-metal.yml` contains:

```
name: ml-apple-metal
 
dependencies:
    - tensorflow-datasets
    - python=3.9
    - pip>=19.0
    - jupyter
    - apple::tensorflow-deps==2.5.0
    - scikit-learn
    - pydot
    - graphviz
    - scipy
    - pandas
    - pandas-datareader
    - matplotlib
    - pillow
    - tqdm
    - requests
    - h5py
    - pyyaml
    - flask
    - boto3
    - pytorch
    - torchvision
    - imageio
    # - dash-renderer
    # - dash
    # - dash-html-components
    # - dash-core-components
    # - plotly
    - pip:
        - tensorflow-macos
        - tensorflow-probability
        - tensorflow-metal
        - bayesian-optimization
        - gym
        - kaggle
        - kaleido
```

Comment: What if you remove `python -m` and just type `jupyter notebook`?

Comment: @MichaelS. yes it works, buuuut I need it to work with `python -m` (it's part of a much bigger problem, that uses that command...)

Comment: Can you provide [mre] steps to let someone create this problem on their own machine? (Building a Dockerfile might be ideal from the perspective of a clean-slate environment you can test and have some assurance someone else can reproduce the environment).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy check what I've just posted, please let me know if you need anything more than that

Comment: Hmm. My Mac uses [Nix](https://nixos.org/) as its only package manager (no macports, no homebrew, etc); not sure if I want conda to touch it, so I may sit this one out.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy It's a bit complex to create a docker since many dependency are apple-related (even though I don't think that they are what is causing the problem)... i need hardware acceleration for Tensorflow

Comment: Try just `python -m notebook`~

Comment: I just tested it with your setup, and `python -m notebook --no-browser` ran just fine on my M1 mac.

Comment: @BeRT2me For real? Can you please post an answer with the steps that you have done?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!

```
python -m jupyter notebook --no-browser
```

Only works *if there is already a jupyter server running*.

So, if you do this in one terminal:

```
jupyter notebook --no-browser
```

And then try this in another terminal:

```
python -m jupyter notebook --no-browser
```

It works... but it does appear to open *another* notebook. Not sure what the work-around is there.

Comment: Ahhh you see… i need that jupyter word, because it’s causing problem on DataSpell…

Comment: The module isn't named `jupyter`, it's named `notebook`... so whatever you're trying to doesn't make much sense. Because the error message is correct, there is `No module named jupyter`.

Comment: It’s the IDE that I’m using that uses that command to launch a jupyter server (dataspell) and it’s causing me that error

Comment: Hmm, it appears that I'm not fully correct. I see where my DataSpell runs `/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/bin/python -m jupyter notebook --no-browser --notebook-dir=...` successfully. There must be some step of your DataSpell configuration that is incorrect. @AlbertoSinigaglia

Comment: It's funny how similar our toolsets are. What are the odds we both have an M1 Mac, use Conda w/ Miniforge, and use DataSpell :')

Comment: I'd make sure your path is explicitly `/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/ml-apple-metal/bin/python`

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia Actually, I think I figured it out. See my updated answer~

Comment: Bu dataspell is working fine on your machine? the last version I mean

Comment: ok, I tried for literally days, and your lovely path solved my issue... miniforge installed with the script from github is broken, the one installed with homebrew works, and I only noticed only thanks to your path that contains the "homebrew"